# Is a LTI filter completely characterized by its frequency response

Tags: filters, frequency-response

I know that we use the frequency response to determine the properties gain and phase delay of a filter. However, I was wondering if this is enough for a complet characterization of the the filter for e.g. in terms of noise attenuation.

For example: I have a low pass filter. Am I guaranteed to attenuate e.g. colored noise?

Cheers,
rot8

Comment: but i would say that initial conditions are not properties of the filter but are property of the initial states of the filter.  in general, i would say that the frequency response (you need both gain and phase) completely characterize the input/output relationship of the filter, just as the impulse response does in the time domain.  But if there is pole/zero cancellation there could be internal states that don't show up in the output.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz we had a similar discussion with MattL about **initial conditions** and LCCDE and LTI ness, however once the term LTI system is triggered then it shall also imply **initial rest** and therefore its frequency response is uniquely specifying its impulse response and that latter completely describes the (observable part of the) LTI system...

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz yes overlap save (block based) processing requires initial conditions (or previous block outputs) but it's not about characterizing the system...anyway not a big deal...

Comment: @Fat32 what about if the filter is causal, anti causal, or no causal

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz unlike Z-transform which requires a region of convergence to distinguish between causal, anti-causal seqeunces, Fourier transform alone can distinguish between causal or anti causal sequences. That's why it's said to uniquely representing $h[n]$. In particular if  $h[n]$ is causal with $H(w)$ then $h[-n]$ will be anticausal with $H(-w)$ and you will have two different Fourier trasforms...

Comment: "For example: I have a low pass filter. Am I guaranteed to attenuate e.g. colored noise?" _Attenuate?_ Very likely; _Eliminate?_ No.